# PHP Sending Form Script

Tags: php, forms, email

I am having a bit trouble getting the PHP script to work. I am making a very basic form just collecting name and email

```
<form action"email.php" method="POST" id="signup-form">
                    <p><input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="name" /></p>
                    <p><input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="email address" /></p>
                    <p class="form-note"><em>* we will only email you when our store is up</em></p>
                    <p><input type="submit" value="Get Notified" /></p>
                </form>
```

My PHP script is

```
<?php
    $error = false;
    $sent = false;

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if(empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email'])) {
            $error = true;
        } 
        else {

            $to = "my.name@gmail.com";

            $name = trim($_POST['name']);
            $email = trim($_POST['email']);

            $subject = "New Subscriber";

            $message =  "Name: $name \r\n Email: $email";
            $headers = "From:" . $name;
            $mailsent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

            if($mailsent) {
                $sent = true;
            }
       }
  }
?>
```

I'm using a Linux hosting company, net registry. I tried to get the PHP errors turned on, but couldn't see how in my cpanel. The mail is not sent, but I have no way of seeing the error preventing it.

Comment: Doesn't work how? Do you get an error? The mail doesn't get sent? What happens? We don't live inside your head and can't know what you're thinking.

Comment: can you send an email from your severs mail server? are you running xampp? or wamp? if so email isn't by default configured

Comment: I updated the post running on a linux hosting server. @AmalMurali

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an error in your html. Try:

```
<form action="email.php"
```

Comment: thanks, what a silly mistake. Now I notice it seems the form is sending but goes to a blank page email.php and nothing still seems to be sent.

Answer (score 1):

Change your HTML to this and try

```
<form action="email.php" method="POST" id="signup-form">
                    <p><input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="name" /></p>
                    <p><input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="email address" /></p>
                    <p class="form-note"><em>* we will only email you when our store is up</em></p>
                    <p><input type="submit" value="Get Notified" /></p>
                </form>
```

Comment: thanks I realized I forgot the equal sign, now when submitting the form, it just goes to the email.php page and nothing is sent to my email